# SQLAlchemy stored procedure is not working in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table called city in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE CITY (
   CITYID serial PRIMARY KEY,
   CNAME VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   STATE VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
```

When I use simple select with SQLAlchemy it works fine

```
query = session.query(models.City)
cities = query.all() #works fine

cities = session.execute("SELECT cityid, cname FROM city where cityid = 1").fetchall() # works fine
```

By doing above, I make sure that my session works fine and connecting the DB properly.

When I try to call a stored procedure in SQLAlchemy it is not working.

Here is my SP (Postgres)

```
create or replace procedure addcity(
   cname varchar(20),
   state varchar(20)
)
language plpgsql    
as $$
begin

    insert into city 
    (cname, state) 
    values (cname, state);

    commit;
end;$$
```

Here is my SQLAlchemy code:

```
session.execute('CALL addcity (?, ?)', [('One', 'Two')])
```

The above code throws error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 369, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 59, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 241, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 52, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 219, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 154, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 40, in run_in_threadpool
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/str-kwml0020/projects/fastapi-crud-sqlite/./main.py", line 128, in add_city
    session.execute('CALL addcity (?, ?)', ['One', 'Two'])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1689, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1575, in _execute_20
    args_10style, kwargs_10style = _distill_params_20(parameters)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/util.py", line 142, in _distill_params_20
    raise exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries
```

I have tried changing the params like below:

```
session.execute('CALL addcity (?, ?)', [('One', 'Two')])
```

The above code throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 369, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 59, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 241, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 52, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 219, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 154, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 40, in run_in_threadpool
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/str-kwml0020/projects/fastapi-crud-sqlite/./main.py", line 128, in add_city
    session.execute('CALL addcity (?, ?)', [('One', 'Two')])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1689, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1583, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1452, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1814, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1995, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1771, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/fastapi38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 717, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: CALL addcity (?, ?)
                       ^

[SQL: CALL addcity (?, ?)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

When I checked SOF, most of the answers quoting the params as list of string. However, having strings inside the list as param didn't help either.

These are the library versions I have used:

```
fastapi==0.68.0
uvicorn==0.14.0
sqlalchemy_filters==0.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.21
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
Werkzeug==2.0.1
FastAPI-SQLAlchemy==0.2.1
Flask==2.0.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
PyYaml
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
```

Comment: psycopg2 does not like the `commit;` in your SP, details [here](https://pastebin.com/5EiMFX2N). I can get it to work with a vanilla psycopg2 connection if I remove the `commit` from the SP and add `cnxn.commit()` after `crsr.execute(…)` in Python.

Comment: @GordThompson I haven't tried the Psycopg2 vanilla SQL. I am working only with SQLAlchemy to get it done. However, I will try your answer as a backup plan. Thanks

Comment: 1) I am not seeing a difference in your examples. 2)`psycopg2` uses `%s` or `%(name)s` as parameters not `?`.

Comment: @GordThompson Your code works on Postgres. I can keep your solution as a plan B. Thanks a lot. However, I am looking for SQLAlchemy supported solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in a comment to the question, psycopg2 does not like the `commit;` in the SP. If you remove that then this will work with SQLAlchemy:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = sa.create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test")

with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    session.execute(
        sa.text("CALL addcity (:param1, :param2)"),
        {"param1": "One", "param2": "Two"},
    )
# automatically commits when the context manager exits (assuming no errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

After @GordThompson and @AdrianKlaver asked some questions I have played around a bit and got this code as a solution

SP:

```
create or replace procedure addcity(
   cname varchar(20),
   state varchar(20)
)
language plpgsql    
as $$
begin


    insert into city 
    (cname, state) 
    values (cname, state);

    # removed commit from the original SP
end;$$
```

Python code

```
cname = "Five"
state = "Six"

session.execute('CALL addcity (:cname, :state)', {'cname' : cname, 'state': state})

session.commit()
```

This works like a charm! Thanks @GordThompson and @AdrianKlaver. You guys saved my time!

Comment: Note that passing a raw string to `session.execute()` is deprecated and will be removed in SQLAlchemy 2.0. From now on we should be passing a `TextClause` to `session.execute()`. We can create it using `text()`.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson for the heads-up. Sure I will make a note of it and fix them soon.